# Multiple functions for live click based on data-filter

Tags: jquery

I have a number of buttons which activate a number of functions on a page but am wondering if there is a shortcut I can use to cut down the code:

Html:

```
<button id="button1">button1</button>
<button id="button2">button2</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#button1').live('click', // click id button1
    MyCode('#example', function () {
    this.button1(); // fire button1 function
    });
});
$('#button2').live('click', // click id button2
    MyCode('#example', function () {
    this.button2(); // fire button2 function
    });
});
```

My question is: if there is a value I can set on the button which can be transferred to fire the click and execute a function with same name inside it... maybe using .data()? If, for example, I have 50 buttons on a page this could be a lot of code/time saved

I have searched but found the info a bit sketchy on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is: if there is a value I can set on the button which can be transferred to fire the click...

You're already doing it: You're putting an `id` on the buttons:

```
$(document).on("click", "#button1, #button2", function() {
    var btn = this;
    MyCode('#example', function () {
        this[btn.id]();
    });
});
```

That uses [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) rather than the deprecated (and removed) [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live). If you're using a an old version of jQuery, then:

```
$(document).delegate("#button1, #button2", "click", function() {
     /* ...same content here...*;
});
```

*(Note that the argument order is different from `on`.)*

In any case: The point is to switch off the `id` of the button.

You might prefer to put a class on the buttons rather than having to list every `id` in the selector, e.g.:

```
<button id="button1" class="btn">button1</button>
<button id="button2" class="btn">button2</button>
```

And

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function() {
    var btn = this;
    MyCode('#example', function () {
        this[btn.id]();
    });
});
```

Further, if you don't want to use `id`, you can use a `data-*` attribute:

```
<button data-func="button1" class="btn">button1</button>
<button data-func="button2" class="btn">button2</button>
```

And

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function() {
    var btn = this;
    MyCode('#example', function () {
        this[$(btn).attr("data-func")]();
    });
});
```

...but there's nothing wrong with using `id` if they're unique.

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks so much, especially for going through the options as they came to you. The class and ID are perfect. Basically allows me to add buttons for new finctions and thats it. Thanks again, much appreciated.